# How to create java application without using any user defined class

Tags: java

How to create java applications without any user defined class?

Comment: A possible hint for you: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: What you mean by "without any user defined class"? It's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: In Java 9 or newer, there's the JShell which will allow you to execute Java statements in the command line (much like you can do with languages such as Python), but other than that you'll need to create at least one class as other users have said.

Some more information about JShell, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm or https://dzone.com/articles/java-9-jshell-in-3-minutes

Comment: See here  program class A{.......////.....} this is user defined class. My question  is that how to write a program without  a user defined  class.  I hope u get clarity on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is an Object-Oriented Programming language. You need to create at least one class to create a simple Java application. You can write applications without classes in other languages like Python, PHP or others, but not in Java.

Comment: It is possible  to make java program without using  User defined class

Comment: I wrote a comment to your code snippet in the another answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you **cannot** create a Java application without your own classes. You need to have your own class to even run the program. If you are trying to ask something else, please be more specific and clear.

Comment: public enum MyFirstEnum{
 
  x;
  public static void main(String args[]){
   int x=10;
   System. out. println("welcome");
   System. out. println("x "+x);
   
   }
  
 }

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: According to docs from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html : "The enum declaration defines a class (called an enum type)", so your code contains class definition too because enum is a class of enum type. It's a special type of class.